# Clone submodules via SSH recursively failing on GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-submodules, git-clone

### Issue

Cloning the repository [git@github.com:revanced/revanced-documentation.git](https://github.com/revanced/revanced-documentation) which contains [submodules](https://github.com/revanced/revanced-documentation/blob/f7770106f8d771893be23837fae9cdf5d06e536e/.gitmodules) fails at cloning the submodules recursively:

```
Cloning into 'revanced-documentation/repositories/revanced-manager'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

### Insight

- The issue can be reproduced locally:

  `git clone --recursive git@github.com:revanced/revanced-documentation.git`
- The repository is using SSH for the submodules:

  ```
  [submodule "repositories/revanced-manager"]
      path = repositories/revanced-manager
      url = git@github.com:revanced/revanced-manager.git
      branch = docs
  ```
- The issue occurs on revision [f7770106f8d771893be23837fae9cdf5d06e536e](https://github.com/revanced/revanced-documentation/commit/f7770106f8d771893be23837fae9cdf5d06e536e) for future reference
- Our [workflow](https://github.com/revanced/revanced-documentation/blob/main/.github/workflows/update-documentation.yml) also experiences [the same issue](https://github.com/revanced/revanced-documentation/actions/runs/4178649863/jobs/7237691447#step:3:15)
- Using HTTP for the submodules should work fine as the repositories are public
- Cloning the submodule repositories manually works fine with SSH

### Note

Because this issue is reproducible locally as well as on GitHub Actions, it is assumed, the issue lies in the repository configuration. A workaround would be using HTTP for the submodules, but SSH is required.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer: [ab]using answer box to provide a formatted comment).

Works for me, no problem:

```bash
$ git clone --recursive git@github.com:revanced/revanced-documentation.git 
Cloning into 'revanced-documentation'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 223, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (35/35), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
remote: Total 223 (delta 18), reused 6 (delta 3), pack-reused 188
Receiving objects: 100% (223/223), 66.31 KiB | 646.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (73/73), done.
Submodule 'repositories/revanced-cli' (git@github.com:revanced/revanced-cli.git) registered for path 'repositories/revanced-cli'
Submodule 'repositories/revanced-manager' (git@github.com:revanced/revanced-manager.git) registered for path 'repositories/revanced-manager'
Submodule 'repositories/revanced-patches' (git@github.com:revanced/revanced-patches.git) registered for path 'repositories/revanced-patches'
Cloning into '/home/phd/tmp/revanced-documentation/repositories/revanced-cli'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2729, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.        
remote: Total 2729 (delta 4), reused 7 (delta 2), pack-reused 2720        
Receiving objects: 100% (2729/2729), 629.85 KiB | 1.88 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (970/970), done.
Cloning into '/home/phd/tmp/revanced-documentation/repositories/revanced-manager'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5843, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (106/106), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (83/83), done.        
remote: Total 5843 (delta 35), reused 72 (delta 21), pack-reused 5737        
Receiving objects: 100% (5843/5843), 20.09 MiB | 7.70 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3208/3208), done.
Cloning into '/home/phd/tmp/revanced-documentation/repositories/revanced-patches'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 21263, done.        
remote: Counting objects: 100% (388/388), done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (216/216), done.        
remote: Total 21263 (delta 118), reused 345 (delta 90), pack-reused 20875        
Receiving objects: 100% (21263/21263), 3.47 MiB | 6.29 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (8043/8043), done.
Submodule path 'repositories/revanced-cli': checked out '567bdee887fff2b7788ee49934e6fcc87a5e8046'
Submodule path 'repositories/revanced-manager': checked out 'eb76bf8593f6ef4b0293ab65dc967d4087c7035d'
Submodule path 'repositories/revanced-patches': checked out 'd1c91f97e553ef2da79a5469e698d58ce15c56bd'
```

Comment: Thank you. This means there is something wrong with my local setup as well as the CI/CD configuration. I will update my post.

Comment: Is your SSH key passphrase protected? I think this might be the cause

Comment: @oSumAtrIX "*Is your SSH key passphrase protected?*" It is but I use `ssh-agent` (`gpg-agent` to be precise) to unlock it.

Comment: Same for me, unsure why the CI fails at last. I was hinted it might be, because of the option `--remote`